# I need a help resolving a PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

Can you please tell me the wrong with this query ?

```
        $q = '%franci%';

        $liveSearch=$stmt->prepare("SELECT keyword FROM keyword WHERE keyword LIKE :keyword ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
        $liveSearch->execute(array(':keyword' => $q));
        if ($liveSearch->fetch() <= 0) {
            echo "no results";
        }else {

            echo $liveSearch->rowCount();

            while($row=$liveSearch->fetch()){
                echo $row['keyword'];
            }
        }
```

In my DB i have two rows

1-> Francian

2-> Franciano

- rowCount() echos **2**
- While gives me only Franciano

Where'is Francian ? And how to resolve this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This if-statement is eating your first record:

```
    if ($liveSearch->fetch() <= 0) {
        echo "no results";
    }
```

Replace it with:

```
    if ($liveSearch->rowCount() <= 0) {
        echo "no results";
    }
```

Comment: Oooops, sorry, i'm really tired, i need a vocation, yeah rowCount() oh my God. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `$liveSearch->fetch()` first time, which gets the first value.

When you are doing the loop, it starts with the second result.

Answer (score 0):

You're pulling out the first result when you do

```
if ($liveSearch->fetch() <= 0) {
            echo "no results";
}
```

You could instead do

```
$liveResults=$liveSearch->fetchAll();

if (count($liveResults)> 0) {
    echo count($liveResults);
    foreach($liveResults as $row) {
        echo $row['keyword'];
    }
} else {
    echo "no results";
}
```